# How do I debug the "500 internal error" when I am trying to get data form '.asmx' webservice using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I am trying to send an ajax request to my asp.net server using jquery and get some data back.But there is no way I can do this it seems.No matter what I do I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` error massege.I know this is a repeated question, but I read almost every thing I could read in stackoverflow and other websites, and none of the solutions helped me.I am trying to debug this thing and figure out what I can do, but I don't know exactly how I must do it

**here are my codes:**

*here's the ajax call:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-item button').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //HTTP method
            url: "/WebServices/RequestHandler.asmx/HelloWorld", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (msg) {               
            console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownerror) {
            alert("something went wrong");
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(thrownerror);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*here's my webservice:*

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class RequestHandler : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;

        [WebMethod]
        public static string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

so as you can see, it is a very simple method, and I am only trying to figure out what is going on and why it is not working

YES, I did omit these two parts :

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

as suggested thousand of times everywhere but it didn't help at all.

And also here's the code when the error messages trigger in the browser console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in &#39;/HelloWorld&#39;.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +489329
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +212
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +346
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +155
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in &#39;/HelloWorld&#39;.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

What I can understand from the error message above, there's something wrong with the url that it is not `"FORMATTED CORRECTLY"` or something and I really have no idea what I can do to solve this error.

Any Ideas would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I also read somewhere that GET and POST requests are disabled by default, so I also added these protocols to my Web.config file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I finally figured it out and as it turns out, it was a problem with my .net framework.I used this tutorial to reinstall the .net framework installed on my machine, restarted my PC, omitted the *`static`* declaration of my `webmethod` and now everything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke your WebMethod using GET, you need to add a ScriptMethod attribute to allow it:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string HelloWorld()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx):

> If a method is not marked with ScriptMethodAttribute, the method will
>   be called by using the HTTP POST command and the response will be
>   serialized as JSON

Alternatively, use POST to access the WebMethod.

Comment: It Did not work.I did added the attribute and then used post method, but still getting the same error